# Hide attachment from embedded images that use cid in outlook email client

Tags: java, email, outlook, html-email, email-attachments

I need to use cid embedded images, I'm using the following methods in java:

```
    MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    byte[] imageDataBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(imageDataString);
    DataSource ds = new ByteArrayDataSource(imageDataBytes, "image/jpeg");
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(ds));
    messageBodyPart.setContentID("<testImage>");
    messageBodyPart.setFileName("testImage.jpeg");
    messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding","base64");
    messageBodyPart.setHeader("X-Attachment-Id","testImage");
    messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-Type","image/jpeg");
    messageBodyPart.setDisposition(MimeBodyPart.INLINE);
    emailBodyAndAttachments.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
```

it looks good in gmail, just like  but in outlook and mac email client I see the image as an attached image:

outlook
[image]

Is there a header that will make it not appear as an attachment?

There must be one because when I drag and drop images into gmail email, they appear without the attachment part and they also use cid.

That's how it looks when I send it from gmail and that's what I also want:

outlook
[image]

These are the headers that gmail uses:

```
--0000000000004076a905f77e39cf
Content-Type: image/jpeg; name="pexels-lisa-fotios-1540258.jpg"
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="pexels-lisa-fotios-1540258.jpg"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: <ii_lfjsr1aq0>
X-Attachment-Id: ii_lfjsr1aq0

/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQ..........
```

and these are the headers that I attached:

```
--_004_CAMNVZSzi1kPoPE3OoJQKBpjw6iFoN2GooxXSKEYAh4pafw4Sgmailg_
Content-Type: image/jpeg; name="testImage.jpeg"
Content-Description: testImage.jpeg
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="testImage.jpeg"; size=3716152;
    creation-date="Thu, 23 Mar 2023 10:18:53 GMT";
    modification-date="Thu, 23 Mar 2023 10:19:19 GMT"
Content-ID: <testImage>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
X-Attachment-Id: testImage
```

The image is referenced as cid in the HTML of course: [image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your HTML body refers to the image through its cid, e.g. `<img src="cid:testImage"` - Outlook will then hide attachments like that.

Comment: I have that of course, I edited the question with screenshot of that.

Comment: What is the HTML body?

Comment: --000000000000568a1005f7903d20
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">asdadasdasd<img src="cid:testImage">qweqeqweqwe

--000000000000568a1005f7903d20--

Comment: try to remove `<` and `>` from `messageBodyPart.setContentID("<testImage>");`

Comment: I tried, and it's the same. This is how the body and attachment section look:

--0000000000003576c505f7f46a44
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">asdadasdasd<img src="cid:testImage">qweqeqweqwe

--0000000000003576c505f7f46a44--

--0000000000003576c805f7f46a46
Content-Type: image/jpeg; name="testImage.jpeg"
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="testImage.jpeg"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: testImage
X-Attachment-Id: testImage

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your last problem is to properly define the CID.
Content-ID property must prefix and suffix with "<" and ">" perspectively, and the value off filename should be same with the content of src of img tag without prefix "cid:"

So you should try it out with the suffix .jpeg

Comment: you can see in the images that I did that and the images work with or without the <>, the attachment is also still there with and without.

Answer (score 0):

In your GMail header it says "Content-Disposition: ***inline***; filename=..." while in yours it says "Content-Disposition: ***attachment***; filename=...". I think this makes it clear, right? Attachments are shown, inline elements are for use in the body only.